# Calcite: Optimize & Rewrite a Query

Tags: java, apache-calcite

I am new to Apache Calcite and currently trying to understand if it can optimize and rewrite a given SQL query string. So far I am unable to find any resources on this.

Is it possible to do this? Any ideas on where to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one of the primary use cases of Calcite. You can see some high-level examples in [the documentation](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/tutorial.html) as well as [this notebook](https://github.com/michaelmior/calcite-notebooks/blob/master/query-optimization.ipynb).

Comment: The notebook helps a lot!

Comment: @Jerry Glad to hear it! If you think of more use cases that would be helpful to add, please let me know :)

Comment: Thanks Michael, I do have one case: how can Calcite modify one given SQL? For example, I may need to add "LIMIT" to a SQL to make sure application security. 
And I want to know how you learn the Calcite project? Since Calcite has 2 RelOptPlanner: VolcanoPlanner and HepPlanner, I was wondering which one is really in use and your notebook helped me on that, but how do you got the conclusion? By reading the code or something else? Since I haven't find any doc explaining that.

Comment: The hard part is, to modify a SQL, we may need to modify the optimized(final) RelNode, since before the stage the filters, sort, and so on may still not be pushed down.

Comment: @Jerry I'd suggest you ask a separate question for that. But you can parse the query, modify the optimized RelNode tree, and then unparse back to SQL.

Comment: Thanks Michael, just asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537311/calcite-can-we-rewrite-the-optimized-relnode