# Calcite: can we rewrite the optimized RelNode?

Tags: apache-calcite

In Calcite, after optimization provided by the default VolcanoPlanner, we can get an optimized RelNode, but can we have a further optimization? For example I want to add an `ElasticsearchSort` or something like that to limit the dataset we handle.

Someone suggests we can define a RelOptRule, but since VolcanoPlanner handles the optimization in `dynamic programming` way, not sure if the rule can be applied in the right order. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain your concern about the rule application order of the VolcanoPlanner?  A custom RelOptRule can determine whether it matches a specific query plan subgraph which is often sufficient in my experience

Comment: What I want to add to the SQL is "LIMIT" clause, I guess I need to add it at the last step, since if added in intermediate steps the query plan may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use VolcanoPlanner. There's also HepPlanner which just applies the rules that you give it as a HepProgram.